# Sharepoint Online Development

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, sharepoint

I am a developer with .net.mvc, angular background. We have some application developed in mvc, angular.
My question is
1. Recently my company want to do the development on share point online(not on premise). I want to develop an app either in angular\MVC which can be deployed and accessed from share point. The app basically calls one of our on premise database displays in a grid. It also involves some crud operation.

Can anyone suggest any ideas for this.

Tried reading through some sites but doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Create SharePoint provider hosted add-in so you could use MVC project web template(a .net MVC project), so you could develop based on your existing .net knowledge.

[get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins)

You could host provider-hosted add-in(MVC web) in azure.

https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9543/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-online-provider-hosted-app

Answer (score 0):

Hey Sorry Your question is getting attacked but I believe I have an approach for you.

Normally youd be able to just create a server side webpart but since you are online you wont be able to use MVC and will need to leverage front end solutions or the SPFx Framework.

If you want to go a more pure javascript route you can create an Angular Application like SPJEFF has done. He has built an Angular App that leverages the SharePoint API and runs inside a content and media webpart that you can embed into the page. Please see his blog post for more info. https://www.spjeff.com/2018/12/25/video-angular-2-cli-todo-list/

Your next option is the SPFx route. Its pretty mature for the online community and constantly updated. Heres a quick read on why you should use it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview

Please message if you have any questions.